# How to edit a Hex code without corrupting the file [in bypassing av]?

Tags: malware, antivirus, reverse-engineering

I recently started studying on bypassing AV by **finding a AV signature** on "nc.exe (NetCat)" and changing it to see how it works. I have already found the place of signature with splitting method then i should **open the nc.exe with a hex editor and change** the Sig. **But**, here is what it look like:

[image]

On another malware i found that the Signature is in last 355byte of the file:

[image]

And both files will get corrupted by editing them (adding or removing bytes)

**Question:** What should i do for editing in this situations? What should i know for a successful binary editing in bypassing av?

If i get this whole wrong tell me what should i be looking for.

Comment: There are multiple formats used in exe files. To modify the file in a way that leaves it still valid you would have to understand how the format is executed and what the section containing the signature does.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16955/bypassing-av-signature-with-hex-editing

Comment: @Hector The sig is in `.text` and `.bss` section, As the code is signed or it don't have WRITE access, should i go for code-cave ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AV signatures are usually based on a hash form a particular file.  They are either known goods, or known bad files.  If it's a known bad file, you can alter a few bytes here and there (for example the "cannot run in dos mode" string), you can have a binary that does the same functionality, with a different hash.

But, most modern AV's / Anti-Malware programs look at a few things; this could include code signing, behavior, etc.

> What should i know for a successful binary editing in bypassing av?

This is exactly what code signing tries to solve.  If you edit the program, the signature will no longer match, and will not be "blindly" trusted.

Bypassing AV is a large subject which is well researched with often insightful techniques.  You can either have an "untrusted binary" which do legitimate things long enough, so that it gets trusted.  Or, have a legitimate binary (ex: something that's shipped with the OS, etc) and try to abuse that to perform something it's not intended to do.

Comment: As i see the signature is in .text section and it just has READ permission and the only part i can change is header and that is not affect that much in front of SymantecEP. Is it possible to unsign it then do changes and sign it again?

Comment: I think you are mixing up "signature" here; you can always create a hash (which is what an AV does with a binary anyway).  You can, if you have th code signing cert always create a digital signature too.

Comment: But, if your question is "can I take a <big trusted vendor> EXE, alter it and sign it again", the answer is no.  That's what code signing is designed to prevent.